# Can magic methods return different result type?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Can a magic method like `def __sub__()` which operates on a type return a different result type?

For example in below class User, the `-1` operator returns a string. The requirement is if there is difference return a string showing representation of the difference.

```py
import copy
class User:
    def __init__(self, username=""):
        self.__user_name = username
    
    def __sub__(self,other):
        if other.__user_name != self.__user_name:
            return "User name changed from {} to {}".format(self.__user_name,
            other.__user_name);
        else:
            return ""
            
    def set_user_name(self, username):
        self.__user_name = username
            
            
user_1 = User("John")
user_2 = copy.copy(user_1)
user_2.set_user_name("Tom")
user_diff = user_1 - user_2
```

After which if we print `user_diff` it will be "User name changed from John to Tom" .

Is this allowed and one of the way to show the difference, mainly the '-' returning a different object type (string) as compared to `User`?

Comment: Yes they can, for example if you have `__sub__` from one `Point` to another `Point` the result should be a `Vector` not another `Point`. There are many use cases where it makes sense to do things like this.

Comment: You can, but I'm not sure I agree with using it like this. While not *required*, you should preserved "expected" behavior in your operations where possible. For example, `(user_1 - user_2) + user_2 ==  user_1` would be nice. If you stray too far from the traditional meaning of an operator, it's better to use a new method instead. `user_1.change_from(user_2)`, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure: a prominent example in the standard library is `datetime.__sub__`, which returns a `timedelta` instance when the other operand is another `datetime` instance.

```
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(d2 - d1)
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```